# Flex override to change return type

Tags: apache-flex, overriding, return-value

I got two classes.

```
class A{
   protected var _value:A;

   public function get value():A{
      return _value;
   }
}

class B extends A{

   override public function get value():B{
      return super.value as B;
   }
}
```

I got error in my overriding and I don't know how to work around. I want to override a method and change it's return value.

Comment: This isn't possible. Can you explain why you want to do that? There might be a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is called [**covariant return type**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type) but is not available is AS3.

Comment: It's a bit complicate to explain(in english) but i try. I got my infra structure and game, I got single tone, that I am using in both Infra and game(I will explain how if you ask), and I got my other singletons that all are members of my main single tone class(application single tone). So my api class need to be excess from infra single tone, then be overrided and excess from game single tone, and I don't want to cast it every time I am accessing it from game. So this is about it, no solution in as3 for now...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change a method signature when you override a method.  You can choose to make the return type a less-specific type (like Object) for both methods - but this eliminates some of the type checking.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the return type or arguments of an override - the signatures must always match.

But your current inheritance model would allow you to return a B for an A:

```
class B extends A {

   override public function get value():A{
      return new B();
   }
}
```

and you could cast the return value to B in the caller method.

Another way to do this would be to set the return type to *, but you would have to take care of type checking yourself.